# Cloudinary Java direct upload BAD REQUEST error

Tags: java, jquery, bad-request, cloudinary

I used Java for building **Image upload** tag:

```
Map options = ObjectUtils.asMap("resource_type", "auto");
options.put("callback", "http://localhost:8080/cloudinary_cors.html");
Map htmlOptions = null;
String html = cloudinary.uploader().imageUploadTag("image_id", options, htmlOptions);
```

Put this String to Model attribute and show on page.  Looks like button ["Choose file"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFEla.png).

Picked some image and **jquery.fileupload** tried to send this image to Cloudinary.

I took **Status Code: 400 Bad Request** and response:

```
error: {message: "Upload preset must be specified when using unsigned upload"}
```

All of my settings is right, I **can send** image from **server side**, using this code:

```
Map uploadResult = cloudinary.uploader().upload("image.jpg", ObjectUtils.emptyMap())
```

but I **can't send** file from **client side**.

**Code of page**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <script th:src="@{/js/common/jquery-1.11.3.min.js}" type="text/javascript"/>
    <script th:src="@{/js/cloudinary/jquery.ui.widget.js}" type="text/javascript"/>
    <script th:src="@{/js/cloudinary/jquery.iframe-transport.js}" type="text/javascript"/>
    <script th:src="@{/js/cloudinary/jquery.fileupload.js}" type="text/javascript"/>
    <script th:src="@{/js/cloudinary/jquery.cloudinary.js}" type="text/javascript"/>
</head>
<body>
    <span th:utext="${cloudyURL}" th:remove="tag"></span>
    <!-- config CloudinaryApi -->
    <script th:inline="javascript">
          $.cloudinary.config({"cloud_name":"CLOUDNAME", "api_key":"APIKEY"});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I read all of Cloudinary manuals, github issues, stackoverflow answers but can't force working direct upload.
Please help me, deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `Upload preset must be specified` error response usually means that the signature isn't passed as part of the upload options. Can you share a URL to a live webpage where this is demonstrated?

Can you also share a demonstration of how the input field is generated (i.e., show it under the 'Developer tools')?

If privacy is an issue, please feel free to contact Cloudinary's support team.

Also, you can have a look at the Sample project(https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_java/tree/master/samples)

Comment: ``<input type="file" name="file" data-url="https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/rrdt/auto/upload" data-form-data="{&amp;quot;signature&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;e9bd431189e380dd53a1b6f248b26370b852812b&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;api_key&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;933157639482912&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;callback&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;http://localhost:8080/cloudinary_cors.html&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;timestamp&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;1434352192&amp;quot;}" data-cloudinary-field="image_id" class="cloudinary-fileupload">``

Comment: Thank you for your response. There are currently some issues with the Java SDK which indeed may cause signed client-side uploads to fail. We're working on fixing it as soon as possible. I'll update once the updated version is released.

Comment: After update to 1.2.1 version, all work fine. The bug was fixed, thank Cloudinary.